# Is there such built-in control in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, controls

I have a list of items with id and description(i can introduce key-value collection instead if needed). What i need is control that binded to viewmodel id property, but shows description of corresponding item/pair on it. Closest example i know is combobox, where i set DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValue/SelectedValuePath, but i don't need dropdown. **So is there any in-built control in Silverlight for this?**

(of course i can code one myself, it's easy and I can even just put some logic for viewmodel to get pair i need and bind it's description to simple textblock)

**Edit:** To illustrate what funcionality i need i coded simple example class. It actually satisfies my needs, but i still want to know if i can use **built-in control**.

```
public class CollectionItemDisplayControl:TextBox
{
    public CollectionItemDisplayControl()
    {
        IsReadOnly = true;

    }

    public string SelectedID
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedIDProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedIDProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedID.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIDProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedID", typeof(string), typeof(CollectionItemDisplayControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedIDChangedStatic)));


    private static void OnSelectedIDChangedStatic(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionItemDisplayControl originator = d as CollectionItemDisplayControl;
        if (originator != null)
        {
            originator.OnSelectedIDChanged(e);
        }
    }

    private void OnSelectedIDChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string description = String.Empty;
        string value = e.NewValue as string;
        if (value != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in _items)
            {
                if (item.UniqueID == value)
                {
                    description = item.Description;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Text = description;
    }        

    private IDataCollection _viewModel;
    public IDataCollection ViewModel
    {
        get { return _viewModel; }
        set
        {
            _viewModel = value;
            if (_viewModel != null)
            {
                _items = _viewModel.Items;
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<IUnique> _items = new ObservableCollection<IUnique>();

}
```

ItemClass contains two properties: ID and Description. I can place this control on the page, bind Items, and one-way bind SelectedID.

**Edit 2:** well i didn't make SelectedID DependencyProperty so binding won't work, but i will fix it right away

**Edit 3:** first snippet was sloppy and didn't work properly, so i fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood properly,

You just need the right binding implemented.

(you do need a list? not just a single item, even if single it's similar just any control)

Bind the list to e.g. `ItemsControl`.

Set `ItemsSource` to your `list of items`

Then override `ToString` on your `Item` providing it's 'yours' really. If not you can make your own wrapper.

Within ToString output whatever is presenting your item, e.g. description.

That's a quickest solution, you can also make item template as you want.

EDIT:
well just put everything in the view model and bind to it - the TextBox, i.e.

```
Text={Binding SelectedText}
```

e.g.
...in your view model add `SelectedText` and `SelectedID` (and `Items` if needed) - properly do `OnPropertyChanged`.

Set SelectedID from view model or if 'bound' from another control that may change it.
Within set for SelectedID set the SelectedText.
No need for a control for things like that, it's all data binding really.

Comment: I need to show only one item from the list at the time - one that has appropriate id. ItemsControl will just show all of them at once.

Comment: well i'll use my own control for now after all.

Comment: you could also attach properties (selectedid and Items) etc. if you wish to go that way (the 'WPF way', controls are hardly ever overriden any more). I prefer (and I think it's better) to work things from the view model side where possible (you can equally 'reuse' your 'small view model' as you would a control.